802.1X freeradius on debian client cisco 2950
I want to authenticate my PC using 802.1X with a Cisco 2950 switch and a up-to-date freeradius on a Debian system.
Here is my Cisco configuration :
radius-server host 192.168.1.195 auth-port 1812 acct-port 1813 key ciscomadesimple
aaa new-model
aaa authentication dot1x default group radius
aaa authorization network default group radius

I will need later to configure switch interfaces in order to authenticate laptops on my office, but on freeradius, clients.conf contains following :
client cisco {
  ipaddr = 192.168.1.111
  require_message_authenticator = no
  secret = <<< secret >>>
  nas_type = "other"
  proto = "*"
}

192.168.1.111 is indeed the IP address as seen by the radius server.
I check from Cisco :
test aaa group radius cisco ciscomadesimple

However, radiusd complains:
Thread 5 got semaphore
Thread 5 handling request 0, (1 handled so far)
(0) Received Access-Request Id 12 from 192.168.1.111:1812 to 172.16.1.10:1812 length 57
(0)   NAS-IP-Address = 192.168.1.111
(0)   NAS-Port-Type = Async
(0)   User-Name = "cisco"
(0)   User-Password = "ciscomadesimple"

I must have missed a step, but so far no clue. Where did i fail ?
